# How to read from file and save in to array in C programing?

Tags: c, arrays, file, structure

I am trying to read from a file that contains multiple lines of numbers and strings and save it to an array. However when I call upon the elements of values stored in that array, and I got incorrect results.

For example if I have a text file that has

```
1:Smith:John:3;43
2:Saget:Bob:5:55
3:Wayne:Bruce:7:21
```

I'm trying to store the objects for the first line in the array in `s[0]`, second line in `s[1]`, and third line in `s[3]`.

Here is my `struct SalesPerson`

```
struct SalesPerson {
    int salesNum; // 4-digit integer
    char lastName[31]; // salesperson's last name
    char firstName[31]; // salesperson's first name
    int salesRate; // commission level for each salesperson
    double salesAmount; //amount the salesperson committed for the week   
};
```

Here is my main function

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "sales.h"
#define SIZE 1000

int main()
{
    struct SalesPerson s[SIZE];

    //opening the file for reading
    FILE * openRead(char salesinfo[]);
    {
        FILE *fp;
        fp = fopen("salesinfo.txt", "r");

        int i;

        if(fp != NULL){

            //read from the file and save it to array s
            for (i=0;i<SIZE;i++){
                while(!feof(fp)){
                    fscanf(fp, "%d:%[^:]:%[^:]:%d:%lf\n" ,&s[i].salesNum,     s[i].lastName, s[i].firstName, &s[i].salesRate, &s[i].salesAmount);
                }
            }
            fclose(fp);
        }
        else
            printf("ERROR! Cannot open the file!\n");
    }
}
```

If I do

```
printf("%d\n", s[i].salesRate);
```

I get all the results for `salesRate`.

```
3
5
7
```

However, when I try a `printf`

```
printf("%d\n", s[1].salesRate);
```

Instead of giving me `5`, I got an incorrect result. Can someone tell me where I am going wrong? Is my for loop condition incorrect?

Comment: Can you provide your entire main function? You've given only half a program...

Comment: sorry, ive included my entire main function now

Comment: See [`while (!feof(file))` is always wrong](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/while-feof-file-is-always-wrong) for a discussion of why your loop is wrong.  TL;DR — test the result of `fscanf()`; do not use `feof()`.

Comment: What is `struct SalesPerson` ? Could it contain `char *lastName` ?

Comment: @SergeBallesta struct SalesPerson has 5 pieces of information that the text im reading from already has. Im trying to create an array that stores those 5 pieces of information. I will post my sturcture int he above question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have an extraneous level of indentation; you really don't need the `{` after the declaration of the unused `openRead()` function, or the corresponding `}`.

You've updated the data to match the code, which isn't entirely fair on [ilent2](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2372604/ilent2) whose [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31957004/15168) was originally pertinent but is no longer as relevant.

You have major problems in the reading loops — one of the problems being that there are two nested loops:

```
for (i=0;i<SIZE;i++){
    while(!feof(fp)){
        fscanf(fp, "%d:%[^:]:%[^:]:%d:%lf\n", &s[i].salesNum, s[i].lastName, s[i].firstName, &s[i].salesRate, &s[i].salesAmount);
    }
}
```

Your inner loop suffers from [`while (!feof(file))` is always wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/while-feof-file-is-always-wrong).  Additionally, you read to EOF for `i == 0`, and the subsequent reads all fail immediately.  (This doesn't tie in with your claimed result: it isn't clear to me what you've done here.)  You should be testing that the `fscanf()` read the correct number of values.  So, you need a single loop, and it should look more like:

```
for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
{
    if (fscanf(fp, "%d:%[^:]:%[^:]:%d:%lf\n", &s[i].salesNum, s[i].lastName,
               s[i].firstName, &s[i].salesRate, &s[i].salesAmount) != 5)
        break;
}
```

Comment: This has fixed my issue. Thank You

Answer (score 1):

If your file has entries like `1;Smith;John;3;43` your `fscanf(fp, "%d:%[^:]:%[^:]:%d:%lf\n"` should contain `;` instead of `:`.  Not sure if this is your only problem, but this is the first that jumps out at me.

<s>You may or may not need the `\n` at the end either since (from memory) `scanf` will discard whitespace sometimes (I'll find a link).</s>

Comment: The sample data has been updated since this (originally correct) answer was given.